movie where hands move around on their own?
All I know is that the movie is horror based and with real actors... 
I only know one scene... I watched it when I was little so it kind of freaked me out and traumatized me.. but I want to see it again.
Scene: 
  In this scene I see a man thats trying to get away from something but he trips and falls to the ground. Next thing you a hand (detached hand, that is able to move on its own and moves around fast like a spider using its fingers) has a knife and plunges the knife into the wrist of the mans hand. He slices it off, and the man hand begins to move around on its own. 
Scene 2 :
This scene that I remember is short... all I remember is that at one point we see  from a worms eye view up towards a building and the next thing you know millions of hands jump from the roof top and onto the ground.

You could also try "The Hand" (1981) or even "The Hand" (1960).

Sounds like Quicksilver Highway from 1997. One half of it is based on a Clive Barker story about a man whose hands revolt against him. You can see the scene where many severed hands jump off a roof in the end here:



